# I can't send a transaction from electrums cli

Tags: electrum, testnet, cli

I am trying to send a transaction in the cli using electrum with the command ~$

> electrum --testnet payto mvYrQck9VfujSanmwvQxiLab3fLuywGdvh 0.01 -f 0.002

Password: (I entered the correct password here)
Q

{
    "complete": true,
    "final": true,
    "hex": "0100000001c36cdc20a497f12731f96b89f830d2743245c4adc1f4a622b8c2e234821cd76e7f0000006a4730440220028106ef3432af605c882db4d9065e318ee6a7513e7731d83a01d3a156985c1d0220256e6213c0bc59f63239a9375636228a6e601b02822bfb28f31adcc15d42e7da0121031720b63d82383198cf67c770d6f8c00877d2721bcb2308ad0717685d706aba55feffffff0240420f00000000001976a914a4e5cdf9a742245b2cb4254640ee2aa16e95809e88ac2cd1cf00000000001976a91457054c8af735007871b7a3697c5736280f59183f88acbd8d1500"
}

but when I open electrums gui I don't see the transaction in the history tab and my balance remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to launch the daemon and broadcast the transaction:

```
electrum --testnet daemon start
electrum --testnet broadcast 0100000001c36cdc20a497f12731f96b89f830d2743245c4adc1f4a622b8c2e234821cd76e7f0000006a4730440220028106ef3432af605c882db4d9065e318ee6a7513e7731d83a01d3a156985c1d0220256e6213c0bc59f63239a9375636228a6e601b02822bfb28f31adcc15d42e7da0121031720b63d82383198cf67c770d6f8c00877d2721bcb2308ad0717685d706aba55feffffff0240420f00000000001976a914a4e5cdf9a742245b2cb4254640ee2aa16e95809e88ac2cd1cf00000000001976a91457054c8af735007871b7a3697c5736280f59183f88acbd8d1500
```